# Where to place javascript unit tests in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, qunit

I have 3 projects in my solution right now. MVC 5, UnitTests and IntegrationTests. Before I deeply involved in JavaScript code, I would like to go with TDD (I have done it for C# but not js before).

I have files under /js folder matches with my controllers. For example myProject.people.js, myProject.company.js etc.

Some people suggests to put test files side-by-side with code base like; myProject.people.tests.js, myProject.company.tests.js. But I am not sure this will be a nice approach for me, since I am using bundles and not comfortable to keep test codes with production code even if it is JavaScript.

I am thinking to create new empty mvc website and cross reference javascript files from one project to another and test this way. Is this an acceptable solution?

What will be the best approach to place test JavaScript files for an ASP.NET MVC Project?

Comment: I don't remember now, but today I would choosing separating front-end logic from the back-end, so I would created separate typescript app and reference it in MVC app.